# unable to access document name in node.js set by as current user email address from fire base

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Set document name as current user email address from flutter application how can I access same documents name in node.js file.

**Data set from flutter application in fire base code**

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('cards')
        .document(user.email)
      .collection('tokens').add({
  'email': 'test@email.com',
  '
  }).then((val){
  });

});
```

I want get it in nodejs file how can I access in this line? what should I write in user.email to access the document name. Do I need to check user authentication in node.js?

```
exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore.document('cards/{user.email}/tokens/{tokenid}')......
```

I can get document name `data` doing so but only static document name
but if I change that to `user.email` or `user.uid` (change according to current user email address or user id not same for all users) so I am understanding how can I get this type of document name.

```
exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore.document('cards/{data}/tokens/{tokenid}').onCreate(async (tokenSnap,context) => {
  const user_id = context.params.data;
  console.log('Document name:', user_id);....
..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Node.js snippet you posted would be how you would create a Cloud Function to listen to changes on documents in the collection. What you probably want is the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) which will let you access documents. The SDK works much like the client SDK:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({...});

const snap = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('cards').doc(email)
  .collection('tokens').doc(tokenId).get();

console.log(snap.data());
```

As another note, unless you have specific reasons for doing so I'd recommend keying documents off of the `uid`, not the `email`, of a user. This is a friendlier format for URLs and will stay the same even if the user changes their email address.

Comment: I can access all those documents name without  admin SDK which I am setting statically but not able to get that documents which set as user.email or user.uid? I am still confused. As I set  data (as document name or any other static name)  from flutter application and I can get that data collection. I updated question please check.